# Static map in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on optimizing the code that creates tens of thousands of maps of type

```
std::unordered_map<std::wstring, std::wstring>
```

The number of possible keys is about 20 and they all are known at compile time.

My idea is to probably have some specialized container with the minimal memory footprint, but ideally with C++ standard-like interface.

The other idea is to have something like std::tuple but with the index of type **char ***. Probably it is a strange idea and I did not think yet on its implementation and I am not sure it can be implemented, but theoretically it can be

```
std::static_map<"key1", "key2", ... > m;
m<"key1"> = "value1";
std::string val = m<"key1">;
```

theoretically there can be an implementation that uses consexpr hash function.

EDIT1: It is a data processing software that collects logs (or messages) over UDP protocol. Once a message is received an MSG structure containing this map along with other data is created. Then MSG is added to the processing queue and after further processing is added to some other queue and so on.... If the processing is slow there can be tens of thousands of MSG's in the queues.

Comment: Best option is probably not to write " code that creates tens of thousands of maps " - your design is probably wrong, but to comment on it we would need far more details.

Comment: @NeilButterworth why not?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is that you're trying to do? With a bit more context we might be able to get a bit more insight into how to help out.

Comment: Tens of thousands of _static_ maps? Obviously (to me, anway) something wrong there.

Comment: @templatetypedef see EDIT1, are you interested in some further details?

Comment: @NeilButterworth probably you are right! It is not tens of thousands of maps, but a table with the tens of thousands rows... I did not think of this before for some reason...

Comment: @NeilButterworth but in this case the question is how to implement a table row that is actually a map (static or dynamic). Probably I need something like DataTable in C#.

Comment: You may want to look up "perfect hash function".

Comment: @NeilButterworth see EDIT1, are you interested in some further details?

Comment: Having said that, `std::wstring` is probably not a very good data type for this purpose (or most other purposes TBH). Why are you using is over plain `string` or a simple `int` identifier?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, definitely the implementation should be based on int, but not on std::string, but if we have a perfect hash they are the same probably.

Comment: @n.m. But the interface with std::string is better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates and populates lots of maps and lots of wstrings, which means lots of allocations.

A first reduction of the allocation effort could be to create the `unordered_map` with already a fixed number of buckets (20 ?).

But given the small number of keys known at compile time,  I'd suggest to have a mapping between the key string to an integer between 0 and the known maximum number of keys. You may then replace the `unordered_map` with a `vector` (also created with a fixed size), and avoid hashing for direct access to any given field.

Depending on the length of the key strings, you could perhaps use a trie to parse the key strings in the input message.

Comment: Yes, probably it will be a simple std::vector, at least I do not know how to implement a 'specific container'.